# Stopping force exerted on a rope. (Checking if rated strength is sufficient)

Tags: strength

I have a 23 kg dog, and a rope lead that is rated to 50 kg.
If the dog is running away at say 6 mph and I pull on the lead to decelerate and stop the dog within say half a second or say 0.5 meter what is the maximum force that could be exerted on the lead?

There are obviously a lot of unknown variables in this,  but as one could imagine in a real world scenario how can I calculate roughly if my lead is going to be strong enough.  Is there a formula I could use to get a rough idea the maximum weight in kg that the lead would be likely to experience.

Comment: *F = m.a* is a good place to start. Answer is in newtons, N. Your rope is rated at 50 x 9.81 = 500 N.

Comment: The deceleration a = (0-2.68 m/s)/0.5s = -5.36 m/s^2. The pull force on the leash F = 23(-5.36) = 123.28 N. The nominal capacity of the leash is T = 50*9.81 = 490.5 N.> F, ok.

Comment: Actually, the total force on the leash will depend on the angle measure from horizontal.. Assume an angle of  30 degrees, the total pull force on the leash F = 23(-5.36)/cos30 = 142.4 N.<< T, ok.

Comment: Re, "a rope _lead_ that is rated to 50 kg." I bet that 50kg is the maximum recommended weight of the _dog._ Tensile strength of rope is almost always specified in kN (kilonewtons). @Transistor pointed out that 50kg of weight equals 500N (0.5kN) of force. But a "rope" rated for a mere 0.5kN would look like a boot lace or maybe even just a piece of string.

Answer (score 0):

The rope has slack causing a jerk and the collar has some play and your arm flexes and changes the angle of the rope. More importantly, our muscles flex by ramping up from zero to a bit more than max level and then hold steady or rather hover at the level.

Ignoring the above the force needed is:

- m = mass of the dog= 23kg
- a, deceleration = $(6 miles/hr)0.5s =  6*0.447= (2.68m/s)/0.5s \quad \text{let's add 20% for the lag in our muscle trigger mentioned above, (3.21m/s)/0.5s = 6.43m/s^2}$
- Leash strength =50*9.8= 490N

$$F= m\alpha =23kg*6.43m/s^2 = 148N <490N $$

If we go by the stopping length we would get:

$$\alpha = V^2/2x \quad \alpha = 3.21^2m/s^2/2*0.5 =10.24m/s^2 \\ F=10.24*23kg =235N <490N $$

So it's okay, mind the dog's neck tho.

**Edit**

On second thought, it would be almost impossible for even an athlete of a 90-kilogram fit body to be able to pull the leash to 50 kilograms to tear it. Unless he has trained caratee and doesn't mind the dog's fate.

Just imagine the body posture of the guy. His body needs to tilt dangerously low, like 40-45 degrees from the level pavement. And because he is pulling a live animal he can not count on solid resistance. With one arm held out flat pulling the leash, impeding his CG offset, and the other arm flailing about.

Long before that he will have to ease off and take a step forward.

Comment: And the lead may also be a spring as it could stretch...

Comment: I know of a lady who had her wrist broke because her body stayed still while her dog accelerated and the weakest point was not the leash...

Comment: sorry met a car paint sprayer the other week - fantastic work and female... very capable with screwdrivers etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to derive the equations to calculate the total force then apart from the actual horizontal deceleration force $F_x$ on the dog you also need to account for:

a) the force that the dog will be applying while you are trying to decelerate it

b) the angle between the dog collar and your hand.

#### Horizontal deceleration force

The actual horizontal deceleration force wrt to time can be easily calculated from

$$F_{x,t} Dt = m \Delta v\rightarrow F_x = \frac{23kg 6[m/hr]}{0.5 [sec]} = 123[N]$$

The actual horizontal deceleration force wrt to braking distance $s$ can be easily calculated from

$$ F_{x,s}= m \frac{V^2}{2s}= 165[N]$$

So, the braking distance of 0.5[m] is more demanding, so that is what we will use in the following part. Therefore:

$$F_{x}  = \max(F_{x,t},F_{x,s}) = 165[N]$$

This however is the average deceleration force. In reality the force distribution over time will be either sinusoidal or triangular like one of the following

[image]

In that case, maximum instantaneous max force will be approximately double.

$$F_{x,inst.}  = \max(F_{x,t},F_{x,s}) = 330[N]$$

#### Dog propulsive force

Regarding the force that the dog will be applying on the floor, in the acceleration stage the force applied by the dogs is reported in ([Rapid acceleration in dogs](https://jeb.biologists.org/content/212/12/1930) as approximately 0.55 times the Body Weight for the hind legs for push off (it actually becomes greater for step 1, 0.65BW and 0.41BW for the Fore limbs). In any case the propulsive force can be high and its about:

$$F_p\approx 125[N]$$

#### Total horizontal reaction force

$$F_{x, total} = F_x + F_p \approx 445[N]$$
This is pretty much insignificant but if you drop to 1[m] horizontal distance or less it will likely start to be significant.

#### Total reaction on the rope

Given that the height of a 23 kg dog is about 0.9 [], and that the average height is about 1.7[m], then the height of the shoulder (arm pit) is about 1.4[m], then there will be  difference of about 0.5[m] in height. Assuming a leash of 3[m] then the angle would be $\arctan(\frac{0.5}{3})\approx 9.5[deg]$

In that case the total force on the leash would be equal to:

$$F_{total} \approx 450[N] $$

So you should be fine with the leash if it was rated at 50[kg] (there is usually a safety factor in there). However as other have pointed out, trying to hold 50 kg with one hand is probably too much unless you are a professional body builder.

#### Final thoughts.

Regarding the modelling and the factors affecting the magnitude of the total force, the most important factor by far is the velocity of the dog. For example if you increase to 10[miles/hr], then the horizontal force triples (to just over 900[N]), while the other factor remain more or less the same.

Finally, although this answer attempts to help with an accurate derivation of the equations of the force, there may not be much point in buying a leash that is rated for 50 kg unless certain precautions are met for the animal  , and certain conditions are met for the animal escort (e.g. over 100 kg body builder with 150 kg benchpress and 400 kg squatting performances  in the last week  - tongue in cheek comment. )

Comment: And the lead may also be a spring as it could stretch.

Comment: that is *mainly* included in the deceleration time. However you are probably right in the sense, that the horizontal force is the average force, while the distribution will more likely be sinusoidal or triangular.

Answer (score 0):

This does not answer your question directly, but the setup below can help you to draw your own conclusion, on the capacity of the leash, and the weight of you required to handle the stop force without falling over :) Note F = m*a, and a = dV/dt.

[image]